# Logout user after inactivity in asp.net core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am new to asp.net core. I am trying to implement User Logout after being inactive for a period of time. Can someone suggest guide/tutorial or explain how to implement this using asp.net core 2.0 and MySql instead of Entity Framework.

Comment: You can use EntityFrameworkCore for MySql as well: https://damienbod.com/2016/08/26/asp-net-core-1-0-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-core/

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Question asking about tutorials and off-site resources are off-topic on StackOverflow. _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it_ Please read the [On-Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) sections before asking a question to get fast and accurate answers

Answer (score 12):

After configuring your identity in the services using `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity` you can configure your cookie `ExpireTimeSpan`

You could read [**Cookie Settings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1) block in the linked article.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

`ExpireTimeSpan` is the `TimeSpan` after which the cookie will expire. `SlidingExpiration` will instruct the handler a new cookie with new expiration time.

Here documentation:

> Summary:
>               The SlidingExpiration is set to true to instruct the handler to re-issue a new
>               cookie with a new expiration time any time it processes a request which is more
>               than halfway through the expiration window.

Answer (score 2):

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
 {
 options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
 options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
 options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
  options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

In .net core 3+ the examples show '$' on the login path and logout. This caused errors when running on lunix. Just remove the '$' and the above worked for me.